# Replacing a specific string in a text file by using C

Tags: c, file, io, argv

I'm a newbie at the C programming language and am having a lot of trouble writing this specific program. This program needs to take user input for a word, which the program will then check in the current directory for all ***.txt** files, search for that word in those files, and replace the word in those files but as an uppercase word. For example, if the user inputs `apple` as an input, then the program would read all ***.txt** files in the current directory (including subdirectories) and replace every single substring as an uppercase of `apple` (`apple` --> `APPLE`; `applesauce` --> `APPLEsauce`).

Here is my current code:

```c
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 1000

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("Enter the target string: %s\n", argv[1]);

    DIR *d;
    struct dirent *dir;
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    char buf[100];

    d = opendir(".");
    printf("Searching in current directory\n");

    if (d)
    {
        while ((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL)
        {
            int length = strlen(dir->d_name);

            if (strncmp(dir->d_name + length - 4, ".txt", 4) == 0)
            {
                FILE *fp = fopen(dir->d_name, "r");
                FILE *ftemp = fopen("replace.tmp", "w");

                while (fscanf(fp, "%s", buf) != EOF)
                {
                    if (strcmp(argv[1], buf) == 0)
                    {
                        printf("%s\n", dir->d_name);
                        printf(("%s\n", &buf));
                        for (unsigned int i = 0, n = strlen(argv[1]); i < n; i++)
                        {
                            argv[1][i] = (char)toupper(argv[1][i]);
                        }
                        printf(("%s\n", argv[1]));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        closedir(d);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I've been able to have the original word stored in `buf` for now, and the uppercase word stores in `argv[1]`.

My problem is that I've been stuck for hours on replacing the string in the **.txt** file with the updated uppercase word. If anybody could provide some guidance, this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hints: (You'll learn more by solving this yourself.) Use `fgets()` instead of `fscanf()`. Use `strncmp()` or `strstr()` instead of `strcmp()`. Always test that `fopen()` works as desired. Finally, close files after they are no longer needed. (The code doesn't write output except to stdout...) Warning: Do this for one file only until you get the substitution working... Then unleash it on all the .TXT files in the directory...

Answer (score 0):

1. foreach directory entry, test if `d_type` is

- **DT_DIR**: directory or
- **DT_REG**: file

2. in case of directory, open the directory and start from 1.
3. in case of file and the extension is ".txt"

   1. [open file](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen) in "r+" (read/write) mode
   2. read a complete line via [fgets](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets)
   3. for each occurrence of search string in line

      1. get the current file position via [ftell](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/ftell) -> `file_pos`
      2. subtract from the file position the length of the line -> `line_pos`
      3. add to the position of the line the position of the word -> `word_pos`
      4. set new file position via [fseek](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fseek)`(file, word_pos, SEEK_SET)`
      5. write the uppercase word into file
      6. reset the file position [fseek](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fseek)`(file, file_pos, SEEK_SET)`
   4. goto 2.

Comment: I'm afraid no arithmetic can be reliably performed on file positions returned by `ftell()` for files open in text mode on legacy systems, especially if there is a newline in the region skipped.  One should use binary  mode (`"rb+"`) instead.

Comment: Also note that this approach may fail to find some occurrences of the search word if lines are longer than the length of the buffer supplied to `fgets()`, which is this case is unable to *read a complete line*.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple program to replace a line from a text file and copying it to  another new text file.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main(){
    FILE* f = fopen("1.txt","r");
    FILE* fn = fopen("1new.txt","w");
    int x=1,k=0;
    char a[100];

    printf("Enter which line to replace: ");
    scanf("%d",&k);
    printf("Write the line to replace: ");
    scanf("%s",a);
    
    char c[100],s[100]="";
    while(fgets(c,100,f)){
        if (x==k){
            fprintf(fn, "%s\n",a);
            x++;
            continue;
        }
        fprintf(fn,"%s", c);
        x++;
    }
    fclose(f);
    fclose(fn);
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).